# Can't initialize object of Detector class from py-feat

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I try to detecting FEX from videos according to this instruction:
https://py-feat.org/content/detector.html#detecting-fex-from-videos

But I can't initialize object of Detector class. Code that I use:

```
from feat import Detector

face_model = "retinaface"
landmark_model = "mobilenet"
au_model = "rf"
emotion_model = "resmasknet"
detector = Detector(face_model=face_model, landmark_model=landmark_model, au_model=au_model,
                    emotion_model=emotion_model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

And I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nilearn\input_data\__init__.py:27: FutureWarning: The import path 'nilearn.input_data' is deprecated in version 0.9. Importing from 'nilearn.input_data' will be possible at least until release 0.13.0. Please import from 'nilearn.maskers' instead.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
Loading Face Detection model:  retinaface
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\mobilenet0.25_Final.pth
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\mobilenet_224_model_best_gdconv_external.pth.tar
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\hog_pca_all_emotio.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\hog_pca_all_emotio.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\hog_scalar_aus.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\RF_568.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\hog_pca_all_emotio.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\hog_scalar_aus.joblib
Using downloaded and verified file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\ResMaskNet_Z_resmasking_dropout1_rot30.pth
Loading Face Landmark model:  mobilenet
Loading au model:  rf
Loading emotion model:  resmasknet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DetectFEXFromVideos\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    detector = Detector(face_model=face_model, landmark_model=landmark_model, au_model=au_model,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\detector.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.emotion_model = ResMaskNet()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\emo_detectors\ResMaskNet\resmasknet_test.py", line 748, in __init__
    torch.load(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 713, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 938, in _legacy_load
    typed_storage._storage._set_from_file(
RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 32606425 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm new to Python, that's why I didn't change any arguments in object initialize. Don't understand what each means.

P.S. And maybe anyone know, how to fix problem in 2 first rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of your files was corrupted.

You can try to solve the problem by opening the directory `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\resources\`
and deleting the file `ResMaskNet_Z_resmasking_dropout1_rot30.pth`.

Then run again the code and it should redownload the deleted file.

The warning in the first two lines is just a warning, it's saying that some of the code in the library `nilearn` is deprecated. Most of the times you would just ignore this line, this will be probably fixed by the coders of `nilearn` in a future patch.

Comment: But I got a new error:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\detector.py:437: FutureWarning: ``multichannel`` is a deprecated argument name for ``hog``. It will be removed in version 1.0. Please use ``channel_axis`` instead.
  hog_output = hog(frame, orientations=orientation, pixels_per_cell=pixels_per_cell,`

Comment: @StanleyKubrik this is not an error, it's a warning, a warning is not critical. It shows some message, but the program runs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Comment: When this warning occurs, also throws exception 'exception occurred' from function process_frame in Detector class.

Comment: can you post the entire message of exception? if this is not related to the original problem it might be worth to open a new question

Comment: It's all message.
That looks like:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\feat\detector.py:437: FutureWarning: ``multichannel`` is a deprecated argument name for ``hog``. It will be removed in version 1.0. Please use ``channel_axis`` instead.
  hog_output = hog(frame, orientations=orientation, pixels_per_cell=pixels_per_cell,
exception occurred
exception occurred`